# Webapi Controller - Routing not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have problem with my webapi controller, can not make it work correctly....

What is wrong?

Here the code:

```
WeabiConfig.cs

        EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{key}",
            defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // this i added
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Action",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
         );
```

MyController:

```
    [ActionName("TransformXMLToHTML")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult TransformXMLToHTML()
    {
        string xsltString  = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Xml/inputXslt.xslt"));
        string inputXml = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Xml/inputXml.xml"));
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString)))
        {
            transform.Load(reader);
        }
        StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml)))
        {
            transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
        }
        return Ok(results.ToString());
    }
```

GET Request: http://localhost:60674/api/comments/TransformXMLToHTML

Error: No action was found on the controller 'Comments' that matches the request

Thanks guys!

Comment: Whats the name of your controller? Can you edit to include the surrounding class definition to the action?

Answer (score 0):

Route matching happens from top to bottom meaning that the first route that matches the given request url will be returned. In this case, the request is matching the `"api/{controller}/{key}"` route which does not specify an a default action.

To rectify, either remove that route, or add some Route constraints to it to ensure that the request in question does not match it.